# VM Software for Windows7/64bit

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I cant decide which is the best **FREE** VM Software for Windows 7 / 64bit.

I want to run an Ubuntu as Playground for couchDB, and to learn some new Linux stuff. Has someone tested the different vm software on win7 with 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Which is the best" is usually not easily answered.

I can only tell that I used [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) successfully on Windows 7 64bit.